# Signaling a thread to terminate whenever it reached a stable situation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrent-programming

Suppose I have two threads `A` and `B`, both running. Suddenly `B` decides to terminate `A`, and thus `A` should terminate ASAP. I don't want `A` to terminate instantly, but when it has reached a stable state.

A naive solution is to use a shared variable `terminatePlease`, which `A` would check for every time it reaches a stable state.

A prototype of the code looks like:

```
class A extends Thread {
    boolean terminatePlease;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (terminatePlease)
                return;
            doUninterruptableTasks();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other concurrency pattern to handle such situations?

Comment: You could replace your `while (true)` with `while (run)` and then use the variable `run` to stop the loop after the work is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the idea, yes. The boolean should be volatile to make this solution work though.

But you don't even need this flag, because each thread has one already: the interrupted flag. So you could just call `a.interrupt();` from thread B, and have your thread A do the following:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        doUninterruptableTasks();
    }
}
```

Note, though, that interrupting a thread blocked in a waiting state will make the blocking method throw an InterruptedException, in order to stop running ASAP. If you don't want that, then use a volatile flag.